# model only runs open "modelbuider"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop.

I have a model made in ModelBuilder which currently does:

1. input XY coordinates excel table
2. data display XY event
3. converting a format event shape
4. add field "name1"
5. add field "name2"

So far so good but my problems are:

1. the model only works so edition
2. I cannot add tool to make a selection of my new shapefile

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "1.the model only works so edition" and I think this must relate to the title you wrote of "model only runs open modelbuider" which is not clear to me either.  In any event, that looks like it should perhaps be asked as a new question because @mapBaker has already addressed the clear second problem/question in a way that I have upvoted.

Comment: sorry for my bad english try to explain 

Error 

1) Click on my toolbox 
2) Right click on my model 
3) open 
4) add data model 
-------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------- 
no error 

1) Click on my toolbox 
2) Right click on my model 
3) edit 
4) add data model

Comment: There's no need to apologize for your English because I admire everyone who asks questions here in something which is not their first language.  Unfortunately, I'm still not sure how to help in this instance.  If there is a problem that you still need help with would you be able to ask this part as a [New Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), please?  That way you will have better options for formatting and we can try to answer that specific question.

Answer (score 3):

Connect a '[Make Feature Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000006p000000)' tool in between the .SHP and the 'Select Layer by Attribute' tools.

> Creates a feature layer from an input feature class or layer file. The
>   layer that is created by the tool is temporary and will not persist
>   after the session ends unless the layer is saved to disk or the map
>   document is saved.

'Select Layer by Attribute' assumes you're going to use a layer in the MXD. To convert any file to a 'layer'. you can use this tool.